# Setting min and max values chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

For a graph I am making with Chart.js, I am trying to set the max. and min values for the X-axis. As you can see from the code below, I am able to easily set these values for the Y-axis, but setting the limits for X is giving me trouble. Please help.

Please view the CodePen here:
[Chart.js JS code to draw a graph](https://codepen.io/varavind/pen/mGGLvw)

```
myLineChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max=20;
myLineChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max=20;
myLineChart.update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you only have 7 labels on the x axis.

If you add more like so by changing labels from:

```
labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
```

to:

```
labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
```

It works fine.

Remember you are asking for a max of 20 but there are only 7 so it can only display 7.

Comment: Thanks for  the input. I am trying to set the range of X axis from 0 to 20. Even though the data ranges from 1 to 7, I would like it to display the X axis 0 to 20. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: change labels to labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] makes it do exactly that

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling with this problem for hours.